# Backbone.js collection.where array includes string

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection of models where one of the attributes (region_list) is an array of strings.
How can I find all the models whose region_list includes a specific string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
collection.filter(function(model){
    return ( _.indexOf(model.get('region_list'), 'specific_string') >= 0 );
});
```

Use Underscore's **[filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter)** and **[indexOf](http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf)** methods to filter all models in the collection whose `region_list` array contains the value `specific_string`.

The return value from this .filter() call will be and array of models.